# IBM MobileFirst 7.1.0 Liberty Server Farm Unresponsive

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-liberty, mobilefirst-server

**Environment Details:**

OS: Windows Server 2012

IBM MobileFirst Platform Server Version - 7.1.0.00.20160401-2103

Project WAR Version - 7.1.0.00.20151130-1648

Application Version - 7.1.0.00.20151130-1648

IBM Websphere Liberty Verison - 8.5.5.5

Java - Oracle JDK 1.7.0_79

**Liberty Farm:**

Two nodes are configured to work with Liberty Farm as Node01 and Node02.

1. Liberty server and MFP are installed on both nodes.
2. Using Server Configuration Tool - Administration services are deployed on both the nodes.
3. Below configuration are added additionally for Liberty Farm.

> jndiName="ibm.worklight.topology.clustermode" value="Farm"
>       jndiName="ibm.worklight.admin.serverid" value="farm_member_1" unique to node
>       jndiName="ibm.worklight.admin.jmx.user" value="myRESTConnectorUser" {Actual value provided in server.xml} 
>       jndiName="ibm.worklight.admin.jmx.pwd" value="password-of-rest-connector-user" {Actual value provided server.xml}
>       jndiName="ibm.worklight.admin.jmx.host" value="93.12.0.12"
>       jndiName="ibm.worklight.admin.farm.heartbeat" value='"5"'
>       jndiName="ibm.worklight.admin.farm.missed.heartbeats.timeout" value='"2"'
>       jndiName="wladmin/ibm.worklight.admin.environmentid" value='"myApp"'
>       jndiName="ibm.worklight.admin.jmx.port" value="9443"

4. Runtime's are created using Server Config tool with common Environment ID
5. Certificate and ltpa.key are exchanged as per the document. [Configuring a server farm](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/install_config/t_server_farm_setup.html?lang=en)
6. Both the nodes are in sync and I can see while I deploy and delete the application from the other.

**Issues:**

1. From worklight Console -> runtime -> Server Farm(Tab). I always see the Status of Node02 is *unresponsive*. But I can access the console of Node02 by http://node02:9080/worklightconsole.
2. If I stop the Node01 and when I access the worklightconsole of Node02 I am getting warning the "No runtime environment deployed in this server".
3. Applications are deployed or removed from any of the server following message is displayed "Node02 seems unreachable, this transaction was not performed on this node."
4. If the Node02 is stopped, while accessing the node01 console nothing impacts.

Is anything else I had missed to make Liberty farm work properly?

**Log:**

```
    [5/23/16 16:20:24:916 GST] 0000004f id=         com.worklight.core.util.RssBrokerUtils                       3 commitTransaction Transaction commit: 2073387200 (new:true; completed:false; rollbackOnly:false)
[5/23/16 16:20:30:344 GST] 00000082 id=         com.worklight.core.jmx.ProjectSynchronizationBean            > pingAdmin ENTRY
[5/23/16 16:20:30:344 GST] 00000082 id=         com.worklight.common.util.BaseProjectLocal                   1 set Set ProjectLocal: MyAPP
[5/23/16 16:20:30:344 GST] 00000082 id=         com.worklight.common.util.BaseProjectLocal                   3 set java.lang.Throwable
    at com.worklight.common.util.BaseProjectLocal.set(BaseProjectLocal.java:56)
    at com.worklight.core.jmx.ProjectSynchronizationBean.setProjectLocal(ProjectSynchronizationBean.java:525)
    at com.worklight.core.jmx.ProjectSynchronizationBean.pingAdmin(ProjectSynchronizationBean.java:466)
    at com.worklight.core.init.WorklightServletInitializer$1FarmHeartBeatRunnable.run(WorklightServletInitializer.java:345)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

[5/23/16 16:20:30:344 GST] 00000082 id=         com.worklight.common.util.BaseProjectLocal                   1 set Set ProjectLocal returned: true [project MyAPP]
[5/23/16 16:20:30:344 GST] 00000082 id=         com.worklight.common.util.jmx.MBeanConnectorFactory          > getLocalMBeanProxy ENTRY com.worklight.common.server.jmx.api:type=WorklightAdmin_MyApp,qualifier=worklightadmin,serverid=Member1 com.worklight.common.server.jmx.api.ManagementMXBean
[5/23/16 16:20:30:344 GST] 00000082 id=         com.worklight.common.util.jmx.MBeanConnectorFactory          1 Detected Liberty profile runtime
[5/23/16 16:20:30:344 GST] 00000082 id=         com.worklight.common.util.jmx.LibertyRuntimeMBeanHandler     > getMBeanServerConnection ENTRY localhost
[5/23/16 16:20:30:344 GST] 00000082 id=         com.worklight.common.util.jmx.LibertyRuntimeMBeanHandler     1 reusing the JMX connection:com.ibm.ws.jmx.connector.client.rest.internal.RESTMBeanServerConnection@4368dce5
[5/23/16 16:20:30:344 GST] 00000082 id=         com.worklight.common.util.jmx.LibertyRuntimeMBeanHandler     < getMBeanServerConnection RETURN
[5/23/16 16:20:30:344 GST] 00000082 id=         com.worklight.common.util.jmx.MBeanConnectorFactory          < getLocalMBeanProxy RETURN
[5/23/16 16:20:30:359 GST] 000000a6 id=         com.worklight.common.util.JNDIUtils                          1 JNDI Access found in cache for context wladmin and key mfp.db.cloudant.username => null
[5/23/16 16:20:30:359 GST] 00000082 id=         com.worklight.common.util.BaseProjectLocal                   1 unset unset ProjectLocal [project MyAPP]
[5/23/16 16:20:30:359 GST] 00000082 id=         com.worklight.common.util.BaseProjectLocal                   3 unset java.lang.Throwable
    at com.worklight.common.util.BaseProjectLocal.unset(BaseProjectLocal.java:114)
    at com.worklight.core.jmx.ProjectSynchronizationBean.unsetProjectLocal(ProjectSynchronizationBean.java:534)
    at com.worklight.core.jmx.ProjectSynchronizationBean.pingAdmin(ProjectSynchronizationBean.java:516)
    at com.worklight.core.init.WorklightServletInitializer$1FarmHeartBeatRunnable.run(WorklightServletInitializer.java:345)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

[5/23/16 16:20:30:359 GST] 00000082 id=         com.worklight.core.jmx.ProjectSynchronizationBean            < pingAdmin RETURN
[5/23/16 16:20:54:918 GST] 00000044 id=         com.worklight.core.tasks.TaskThread                          3 trigger Triggered task com.worklight.core.clustering.ClusterSynchronizationTask#4a43c9dc
[5/23/16 16:20:54:918 GST] 0000004f id=         com.worklight.core.util.RssBrokerUtils                       3 beginTransaction Transaction begin : 539749812 (new:true; completed:false; rollbackOnly:false)REQUIRED
[5/23/16 16:20:54:918 GST] 0000004f id=         com.worklight.core.clustering.ClusterSingletonDetails        1 ClusterSingletonDetails VMID:NodeAPP1:b02b3977865adf5c:2df65b64:154dd8a8a29:-8000
[5/23/16 16:20:54:918 GST] 0000004f id=         com.worklight.core.clustering.ClusterSingletonDetails        1 ClusterSingletonDetails VMID:NodeAPP1:b02b3977865adf5c:2df65b64:154dd8a8a29:-8000
[5/23/16 16:20:54:918 GST] 0000004f id=         com.worklight.core.clustering.ClusterSingletonDetails        1 ClusterSingletonDetails VMID:NodeAPP1:b02b3977865adf5c:2df65b64:154dd8a8a29:-8000
[5/23/16 16:20:54:918 GST] 0000004f id=         com.worklight.core.clustering.ClusterSingletonDetails        1 ClusterSingletonDetails VMID:NodeAPP1:b02b3977865adf5c:2df65b64:154dd8a8a29:-8000
[5/23/16 16:20:54:918 GST] 0000004f id=         com.worklight.core.util.RssBrokerUtils                       3 commitTransaction Transaction commit: 539749812 (new:true; completed:false; rollbackOnly:false)
[5/23/16 16:21:24:928 GST] 00000044 id=         com.worklight.core.tasks.TaskThread                          3 trigger Triggered task com.worklight.core.clustering.ClusterSynchronizationTask#4a43c9dc
[5/23/16 16:21:24:928 GST] 0000004f id=         com.worklight.core.util.RssBrokerUtils                       3 beginTransaction Transaction begin : 973144513 (new:true; completed:false; rollbackOnly:false)REQUIRED
```

Answer (score 0):

The symptom shows that JMX connection between the nodes is not working at all.

You do not mention how you did set the field **ibm.worklight.admin.jmx.port**. Check the log file whether it contains the message "*JNDI properties needed for JMX transport are not set*". If that's the case, please set the port property. Clearly JMX will not work if the port property is not set.

I hope that "*myRESTConnectorUser*" and "*password-of-rest-connector-user*" are not the literal values in your configuration; they should be replaced by an actual user and password.

For details how to configure a liberty farm see [the IBM Knowledge Center here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/install_config/c_farm_topol.html).

Comment: Of course yes, JMX port value was provided with actual. If this is not set then how can Scenario 1 will work? JNDI user & password are actual in the sever.xml as i have updated in the question. I have added logs.

Answer (score 0):

This is was resolved by creating New Liberty Server instance & IBM MFP Liberty Farm configuration.